# Como puedo subir imagenes a parse server desde express

Tags: javascript, express, parse.com

express code

```
app.post('/upload', multipartMiddleware, function(req, resp) {
  var restaurante = new Parse.Object("Restaurante");

  var logo =(req.files.imagen);
  var file = new Parse.File("logo", req.files.imagen);

  restaurante.set("logo",file);
  restaurante.save();
});
```

El formulario desde donde envío el archivo es

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <a href="#!"  class="modal-action modal-close">
      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <h5>Elige archivo</h5>
    <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="btn file-upload-button">
            <span>Archivo</span>
            <input type="file" name="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Continuar</a> 
        </div>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

y lo que me imprime es lo siguiente

esto es lo que contiene console.log(logo);

```
 { fieldName: 'imagen',
      originalFilename: '511c67187eadd5b4f2a22e5f0af12c9a_tikua.png',
      path: '/tmp/kR1rUFxfxZFeE3u4uoH7Y-f7.png',
      headers: 
       { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="imagen"; filename="511c67187eadd5b4f2a22e5f0af12c9a_tikua.png"',
         'content-type': 'image/png' },
      size: 10331,
      name: '511c67187eadd5b4f2a22e5f0af12c9a_tikua.png',
      type: 'image/png' }

TypeError: Cannot create a Parse.File with that data.
```